# Have Plotly Load Automatically onto a Webpage

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using plotly to display graphs on a page for a course that I am developing.  I can create the graphs when student's click on a button using the code below:

```
    if($('#lesson1AssignmentGraphButton').length){

    $('#lesson11AssignmentGraphButton').click (function (){

        if($("#lesson15AssignmentGraph").html() === "") {

            create plotly graph

        }

    });

}
```

Is there a way to have the graph automatically be added to the webpage (html document) without the user having to click on a button?

Edit:

Thank you testing testing_22.  I tried your code but was not successful.  For Bas van der Linden comment, I completely agree.  However, I seem to always have difficulty with having the graph show on the page.  An example code that I use on my page is

```
    if($('#lesson11StudentScatterButton').length){

    $('#lesson11StudentScatterButton').click (function (){

        if($("#lesson11StudentScatterGraph").html() === "") {

            let trace1 = {
                x: [1, 5, 5, 8.5, 4, 7, 9, 1, 7],
                y: [9, 6, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 7, 5],
                mode: 'markers',
                type: 'scatter'
        
            };
        
            let layout = {
        
                autosize: true,
        
                margin: {
                l: 50,
                r: 10,
                b: 40,
                t: 40,
                pad: 5
                },
        
                title: 'Number of Cups of Coffee vs<br />Hours of Sleep',
        
                xaxis: {
        
                    title: 'Number of Cups of Coffee',
                    showgrid: true,
                    zeroline: true,
                    showline: false,
                    range: [0, 10]
        
                },
        
                yaxis: {
        
                    title: 'Hours of Sleep',
                    showgrid: true,
                    zeroline: true,
                    showline: false,
                    range: [0, 10]
        
                },
        
                plot_bgcolor:"#f8f1f1",
                paper_bgcolor:"#f8f1f1"
        
            };
        
            let data = [trace1];

            let config = {

                showSendToCloud: true,
                displayModeBar: false,      // this is the line that hides the bar
                scrollZoom: false,
                responsive: true
    
            }
        
            Plotly.newPlot('lesson11StudentScatterGraph', data, layout, config);

            $("#lesson11StudentScatterButton").html("Hide Graph");
            $("#lesson11StudentScatterButton").removeClass("createQuestionsButton").addClass("checkAnswerButton"); 
            
        }   else {

                document.getElementById("lesson11StudentScatterGraph").innerHTML = "";

                $("#lesson11StudentScatterButton").html("Scatter Plot");
                $("#lesson11StudentScatterButton").removeClass("checkAnswerButton").addClass("createQuestionsButton");

        };

    });

}
```

When I have a student click on button, the graph shows up fine and with no issues.  When I try to remove the click event and have the graph show directly up on the page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

if($("#lesson11StudentScatterGraph").html() === "") {

    let trace1 = {
        x: [1, 5, 5, 8.5, 4, 7, 9, 1, 7],
        y: [9, 6, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 7, 5],
        mode: 'markers',
        type: 'scatter'

    };

    let layout = {

        autosize: true,

        margin: {
        l: 50,
        r: 10,
        b: 40,
        t: 40,
        pad: 5
        },

        title: 'Number of Cups of Coffee vs<br />Hours of Sleep',

        xaxis: {

            title: 'Number of Cups of Coffee',
            showgrid: true,
            zeroline: true,
            showline: false,
            range: [0, 10]

        },

        yaxis: {

            title: 'Hours of Sleep',
            showgrid: true,
            zeroline: true,
            showline: false,
            range: [0, 10]

        },

        plot_bgcolor:"#f8f1f1",
        paper_bgcolor:"#f8f1f1"

    };

    let data = [trace1];

    let config = {

        showSendToCloud: true,
        displayModeBar: false,      // this is the line that hides the bar
        scrollZoom: false,
        responsive: true

    }

    Plotly.newPlot('lesson11StudentScatterGraph', data, layout, config);
    
}
```

});

The graph will not load on the page.  When I check the console, it does not show any errors.  I am sure there is a simple method to do this but it escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Maybe `$( window ).load(function() { ... } )`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.  I have also tried $( document ).ready(function() {} but when I load my page, the graph does not display.

Comment: Try mocking a click through `$('#lesson11AssignmentGraphButton').click()` when page loads in addition to the existing functions

Comment: Maybe I'm reading the question wrong, but can't you just put the plotlyjs code in a script tag and it just works? https://plotly.com/javascript/line-and-scatter/. If you have a dom element you can identify with an id, you can use `newPlot` to create a plot in the place of the dom element.